# How to customize google gantt chart to have collapsible items?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, gantt-chart

I am using gantt chart from google [[LINK HERE]](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart)
The current view is like this :
[image]

But I like to add collapsinle items like this :

[image]

how to make it like this? Each heading should have a chart items also each members.
Thanks in advance

Comment: you could draw a separate chart within each accordion but there aren't any options that will make the chart collapsible...

Comment: or can i make each heading highlighted than subitems and align subitems difeerently?